# Reverse substitution

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

If you apply rules and then simplify you may get something like.

```
(25 A^2 hbar Sqrt[π])/Sqrt[hbar m w]
```

How would you get mathematica to rewrite this in terms of E where

```
E -> Sqrt[ m w/ hbar ] x
```

It's very easy to plug E into things, but I don't know how to get it back out.
Further, I keep running into situations where I wish I could do this, and then end up having to finish what I am doing on paper. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr = (25 A^2 hbar Sqrt[π])/Sqrt[hbar m w];
```

Presumably, your `E` is not intended to be the numeric constant `2.71828...` Using `\[DoubleStruckCapitalE]` instead

```
rule = \[DoubleStruckCapitalE] -> Sqrt[m w/hbar] x;
```

Assuming that `{m > 0, w > 0, x > 0, \[DoubleStruckCapitalE] > 0}`

```
expr /. Solve[Equal @@ rule, hbar][[1]] //
 Simplify[#, {m > 0, w > 0, x > 0, \[DoubleStruckCapitalE] > 0}] &

(* (25 A^2 Sqrt[π] x)/\[DoubleStruckCapitalE] *)
```